# How to change the background series colour of Highcharts Radar chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to change the background colour of my Highchart radar chart.

[image]

As you can see there's just the border lines for the area. I want that area filled with the same colour as the border. I thought to add `backgroundColor: 'Red'` to the series I.E.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Similar',
        data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        backgroundColor: 'Red'
    }, { ... }
```

Instead this has no effect and the chart looks the exact same as above. How can I fill this area with a colour, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "radar chart" (aka "spiderweb") in Highcharts is just a regular chart with [`polar: true`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.polar).

This means that the series themselves are of the regular types like "line", "area", etc. In your case you seem to be using "line". Instead switch to using `type: 'area'` which will then fill the area below the line. Optionally supply a `fillOpacity` if you want the background to be solid.

As an example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bthjwgw/)):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true
    }
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        fillOpacity: 1.0,
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000]
    }
});
```

The series type can be set either for each individual `series` or globally in `chart`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you answered my question perfectly!